# Sample tornado web request

Tags: python, tornado

I'm making a sample tornado application. For the first method, I'd like it to return the string "OK", instead of rendering a template. How would I do the following:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Regular HTTP handler to serve the ping page"""
    def get(self):
        self.render('Hi') # expects template instead of string -- how to do string?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `write` method:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Regular HTTP handler to serve the ping page"""
    def get(self):
        self.write("OK")
```

Comment: You should use `self.finish("OK")`, that will be better if you have a complex function.